# Popup coding shows not action

Tags: javascript, jquery

This a popup for a website have  function

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    setTimeout(function() {         
        $.fn.colorbox({ html: '<iframe width=600 height=550 src=../sumthing.html>  </iframe>'
    });     
}, 100); });
```

This directs to a sumthing.html file

```
<form method="post" action="popup2.php"  >...... </form>
```

But instead action for popup2.php file which is validation for sumthing.html form it shows coding of that file

Any suggestion for what to do

Comment: double check that your server has its php module correctly configured and the file has the appropriate opening/closing parenthesis (`<?php` and `?>`).

Comment: Hi It was working perfectly before using in colorbox function so I think files are correct

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing the code of the `popup2.php` file when the form is submit it sounds like your host does not support PHP, or it has not been correctly configured.

Comment: Do you have a LAMP/WAMP server setup on your machine?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning before                I have Xampp server telling you again it was working fine till I called it in colorbox I tried to change this file into PHP making validation and form in same page then also its not taking PHP part of validation  I have used jquery.colorbox-min.js and https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js jquery files Since I dnt know how to work on these files I think I have Problem For PHP working

Comment: You did not mention before that it was at one point working correctly. That information should be in the question.